# How to efficiently list files that have exactly `n` lines?

Tags: bash, performance, file, awk, find

In order to list files that have exactly `n` lines, one can do

```
n=5
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs wc -l | awk -v n=${n} -F" " '{if ($1==n) {print $2} }'
```

but this solution is quite slow as it counts the number of lines for each file first and then only select those that have `n` lines. A process that would count the lines and stops when it reaches `n+1` lines would be much more efficient (esp. when dealing with big files that have plenty of lines).

**How to efficiently list files that have exactly `n` lines?**

Note, for the special case, where each line is of exactly the same size, then one could probably do

```
n=5
sizePerLine=500
find . -name '*.txt' -size $(( ${n} * ${sizePerLine} ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following would be faster:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec awk -v n="$n" 'FILENAME != prevfile {if(prevfnr==n) print prevfile} {prevfile = FILENAME; prevfnr = FNR; if(FNR>n) {nextfile;}} END{if (FNR==n) {print FILENAME} }' {} +
```

How it works:

- use `-exec ... {} +` to use `find` to execute the command for each file, and let it pass many args per invokation
- `awk -v n="$n"` invoke `awk` and define an `awk` variable called `n` to have the same value as the shell variable `n`
- `FILENAME != prevfile {if(prevfnr==n) print prevfile` checks if the current file is the same as the last record was in, and if not see if the previous file had exactly `n` records, if so print the name of that file
- `{prevfile = FILENAME; prevfnr = FNR; if(FNR>n) {nextfile;}}` update the `prevfile` variable with the current `FILENAME` and the `prevfnr` variable with the current `FNR`.  Also, if our current file record is over `n`, jump to the next file without processing anything more here
- `END{if (FNR==n) {print FILENAME}` at the end see if the last file also had exactly `n` records

Interestingly, I found that this actually gives different results than the version that uses `wc -l`, though I think this one is probably actually more correct.  For files in my directory whose last line does not include a line ending character `wc -l` would report the number of lines, not counting the last "unterminated" line, but the solution here will count it.

Arg, I had failed to appreciate that `nextfile` is a GNU-ism.  If I'm already limiting myself to that we can make this much cleaner as

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec  awk -v n="$n" 'FNR > n {nextfile;} ENDFILE{if (FNR==n) {print FILENAME} }' {} +
```

it doesn't seem to me that POSIX `awk` has a good shortcut to jump to the next file, which is the key that this solution needs for it's efficiency

Comment: If it makes you feel better, a file that doesn't end in a newline technically is not a text file. See [3.206](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) and [3.397](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_397) in the POSIX spec.

Comment: You are correct, there is no way in POSIX awk to stop processing a file (except `exit`) which is why `nextfile` was introduced as an extension to gawk. The solution you ended up with [looks familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39434305/1745001)...

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, I guess that's pretty nearly verbatim your solution. . . I often get to yours eventually!

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 -n 1 awk -v n="$n" 'NR>n{exit} END{if (NR==n) print FILENAME}'
```

or even more efficiently with GNU awk for ENDFILE:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec \
awk -v n="$n" 'FNR>n{nextfile} ENDFILE{if (FNR==n) print FILENAME}' {} +
```

The main efficiency in the above script is exiting the awk work loop (i.e.jumping to the END/ENDFILE section) as soon as you hit a line number greater than `n` rather than waiting until the whole file has been read before checking the number of lines read.

To show the difference between `nextfile` and `exit` in a gawk script:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '{print; nextfile} ENDFILE{print "x"} END{print "y"}'
1
x
y

$ seq 10 | awk '{print; exit} ENDFILE{print "x"} END{print "y"}'
1
y
```

Comment: I believe `exit` will quit `awk` for good, instead of looking for more files with 5 lines.  You might try `gawk`'s `nextfile` instead of `exit`; I tried that myself, but I didn't manage to make it work reliably, apparently because `ENDFILE` is not called after `nextfile`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura you're right that it should be `nextfile` in the 2nd (gawk) example. `nextfile` takes you to `ENDFILE` while `exit` used in the awk body takes you to `END`. I've updated that script.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
n=5
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs grep '.+' -m $((n+1)) -c | grep ':'$n'$'
```

This tells `grep` to only examine the first `n+1` lines, and to show you only the files that have `n` lines.

Substitute `xargs ag '\n' -m$n -c` if you have it for a nice speedup - `ag` is a much faster searcher than `grep` is. Note that `-m` only works properly on GNU grep; on BSD grep, it is a global option (use `ag` instead, or get GNU grep).

Comment: My `grep` (`GNU grep 2.16`) matches any character followed by a `+` with that command, unless I add the `-E` or use `egrep`.  It also doesn't count blank lines either way, so would give a different answer from `wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

Using awk itself:

```
n=5
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -n 1 awk -e "{ n++; if (n > $n) {exit 1} } END { if ( n == $n ) print FILENAME}"
```

This will quit as soon as file has +5 lines otherwise will print if exact 5 lines.

Comment: This only seems to search the first file it encounters for me, then exits without considering the next, though if I add `-n 1` to `xargs` it gets them all--but only if the filenames are "nice" using `-print0` and `xargs -0` helps with that too though

Comment: you are right. -n 1 is mandatory to work and I will correct, maybe the better approach here should use -exec as you pointed out in your solution. I will make the changes. thks

Comment: However, `xargs -n 1` will spawn an `awk` process for each file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be wildly over complicating what you can simply use a `for` loop and a `test` condition to evaluate, e.g.

```
for f in *.txt; do [ $(wc -l <"$f") -eq "5" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

This will find all `.txt` files in the current directory that contain `5` lines.

Comment: This wouldn't decend into nested directories though, so might miss a lot of the files to be considered

Comment: To descend into directories below, simply use `find` to feed a `while` loop doing the exact same thing, e.g. `while read -r f; do ....; done < <(find . -type f -name "*.txt")`

Comment: The more serious problem here is that `wc -l` would read all files to the end, to find the number of lines.  Most other solutions posted try to bail out after reading the first few lines, to save time.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
n=5 find /some/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
    perl -lnE '{ $. == $ENV{n} and eof and say $ARGV } continue { close ARGV if($. == $ENV{n} or eof) }' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` and `awk`:

```
$ grep -cr "^" *|awk -F: '$2==6 {print $1}'
```

Breakdown:

- `grep -c` counts the amount of matching lines in file
- `-r` is --recursive
- `"^"` to match (ie. count) beginnings of lines

`grep`'s output is:

```
foo:6
dir/bar:7
```

- `awk` uses `:` as field separator and print filenames (and related paths) of files where line count is the given.

Comment: You have re-invented `wc -l` with `grep`.  This has the same problem as `wc -l`: it reads all files to the end, instead of quitting after the first few lines.

Comment: Valid point, didn't think about it at all, merely wanted to present an alternative to `find`.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient solution would be to use `find` with `gawk` using the condition [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) with [`FNR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records).

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk -v n=$n 'ENDFILE{if(FNR==n) print FILENAME}' {} +
```

This cuts time in half on the order of number of files for any solution that requires piping the entire output of `wc -l` to another process that parses its output.  That said, other answers using `ENDFILE` with `nextfile` are even more efficient as they allow for skipping to the next file when the desired number of lines has been reached.

Assuming you are using Bash > 4.0, one could remove the need for `find`, to take advantage of the `globstar` bash option that allows for the expansion of filenames recursively.  This should work so long as the number of arguments doesn't exceed `gawk`'s `ARGC` limit.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ gawk 'ENDFILE{if(FNR==n) print FILENAME}' **/*.txt
```

Comment: This reads all files to the end, which is essentially as bad as `wc -l`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Not nearly as bad as a `wc -l` solution. In fact, it cuts time in half as any solution that uses `wc -l` like the OP does must have each line of its output parsed again by another process like `awk`. That said, it wold definitely be more efficient if it used `nextfile` as @EricRenouf's solution does.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash≥4, here's a rather efficient way to check whether a text file has 5 lines:

```
mapfile -n 6 -t lines < file
if (( ${#lines[@]} == 5 )); then
    echo "has 5 lines"
else
    echo "doesn't have 5 lines"
fi
```

We use `mapfile` with `-n 6` so that no more than 6 lines are read (for efficiency).

Together with a `find` command, we obtain:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec bash -c 'mapfile -n 6 -t lines < "$1"; ((${#lines[@]}==5))' _ {} \; -print
```

You can also use `-exec ... +` and a loop inside the bash statement (exercise left to the reader).